# Stellar KYC - Not Found when creating a customer {{ANCHOR_SERVER}}/sep12/customer

Tags: stellar-sdk, anchor, stellar.toml

My anchor is up and running without issues, but when I try to start KYC (SEP12) for a customer, it returns a Not Found.

Request: `PUT`

URL: `{{ANCHOR_URL}}/sep12/customer`

Request Body:

```
{
    "account":"GBJDHUVTZ5TUXEWEV6DHYDJUHIBLBG7HEBTUBBIU6BDDSMB78CW5XT",
    "memo":"1234567890",
    "memo_type":"text",
    "type":"sep6-sender"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Am i missing something at this point?